Cause of "no pg_hba.conf entry for host" in Postgres (AWS RDS)
I am using Postgres engine 16.3 on RDS and can successfully connect to and run my program.
My program is a batch process as part of ETL and processes sequential data from JSONL file.
In increased the number of threads doing the same work (SELECT and some INSERT) and sometimes get the following error:
no pg_hba.conf entry for host
It seems as though the thread count breaches the CPU limit, and after a short allowable burst, it starts declining queries. Lowering the thread count has has had a positive effect.
But sometimes, after an hour or so I might get the odd error. Which is super annoying.
Given how my process is built, it means I need to restart that particular file.
What causes this intermittent error and how can I confidently prevent it if I am going to run a batch for upwards of 24 hours (first run).
EDIT
The JSONL files consist of 2200 lines, with each line containing 40 objects.
For each object I query the database to see if it exists (by ID). If not I insert it.

It is hard to see how load-specific issues could cause that error, unless you are trying to go through multiple connection poolers but only one of this allowed, or something like that.  Also, that is not the entirely of the error message, the rest of it might be informative too.

Ok, i'll keep a note of the full message next time.
I am using a GORM package for Go, so I will have a look at how it might be replicating connections under the hood. Thanks.

For the benefit of future readers of this question:
I had been using an IAM user linked into RDS for authentication .. but seem to have solved the problem by switching back to native Postgres user accounts.
I believe the RDS IAM Auth gateway is not capable of handling larger traffic volumes.
My two cents is that RDS IAM is useful to link in user access to RDS instances with IAM... but for service accounts, native PQ user accounts are better.
Since switching, I have amped up concurrency on my batch jobs and not noticed this issue, even once!
